# MYSQL doesn't select next row

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm trying to create a select-field with options, the options are stored in the database.

The table looks like this:

```
id  option   class
1   opt1     cl1
2   opt2     cl2
3   opt3     cl3
4   opt4     cl4
```

my code looks like this:

```
mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    //select DB
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

    //query
    $query = "  SELECT * 
                FROM `".TBL_OPTIONS."` ";

    //result query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // fetch query results
    $records = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    //var_dump($records);

    echo "<select>";
    foreach($records["id"] as $id){
        echo "<option id=$id>";
        echo $records["naam"];
        echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

It only returns me the first row. It then stops.
my var_dump which is commented out shows that it only selected row one too.
Any help? :)

Comment: You clearly need to read again what `mysql_fetch_array` is actually doing: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Where is your `while` loop? Read the examples: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Again and agin, stop using `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: also, re-think the logic. note the program efficiency is now `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option id=$row['id']>";
    echo $row["naam"];
    echo "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Any reason to downvote it..??

Comment: same for me was a couple seconds late for the win i suppose.

Comment: Even I got downvote for that

Comment: First tell me the reason to downvote....the one who downvoted this will need think

Comment: ill accept this answer to make you feel better.

Comment: No need....Iam not begging for anything....iam just asking for the reason....

Answer (score 3):

Of course it fetches only one record. `mysql_fetch_array()` only gets the current row. To get all rows, you would need to loop over it.

```
while($records = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //Do something
}
```

Please note that `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated and not supported by PHP. You should use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something wrong with my looping but just couldn't lift my finger on it.